# android studio 2.0 gradle 2.0 build successful. but toast error

Tags: android-studio

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhHc0.jpg]

Android studio update to 2.0 toast this error
I don't know why!
Has anyone meet the same question?
Please help me out

Comment: Where is your code, ask a question with showing your work, so that others can help you

Comment: I use gradle 1.5 is OK，but gradle 2.0 can build successful,can generate apk also. but the toast says error.

Comment: But in your screenshot it says that `Gradle build finished with 400 errors` So you need to correct those 400 errors

Comment: I just can't understand,  it build successful,can generate apk normal,but toast show error.I think my code has no errors

Comment: it is not build successfully, if it build successfully then there should be like `Gradle build finished with 0 errors`. in your case it has 400 errors in it though it build successfully

Comment: Same here. http://imgur.com/saFfoTA